# Convert .out file to .pdf using shell script

Tags: shell-script, pdf

I have a `.out` file I want convert this file to PDF format. Is there any script available for this?

File Format :o53770855.out

I want to convert this into o53770855.pdf

Comment: What application produced that ".out" format?

Comment: Please give us an example of the file. What format is it?

Comment: If the file is too large to easily post online and you don't know what application was used to create it, [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/91908/edit) your question to include the output of `file -s FILENAME.out`.

Comment: The file _name_ doesn't help. We need to know what _format_ it is: plain text, html, xml, markdown, ...? Show a few lines if you don't know the format.

Answer (score 4):

If it's just a text file you can use the command `text2pdf` to do this:

```
$ text2pdf -o <pdf file> <text file>
```

#### Example

Here's a sample file.

```
$ cat test.txt 
This is a test file.
```

Converted to PDF:

```
$ text2pdf -o test.pdf test.txt
```

Results:

[image: sample pdf]

Not sure about other distros but the command `text2pdf` is part of the package `pdflib-lite` on Fedora.

#### References

- [text2pdf main website](http://www.eprg.org/pdfcorner/text2pdf/)